# Extract number from a string value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parsing, numbers

I have a varchar that always come into this format:

'PB' + multiple Leading 0 + Number + Non-Number Character(s).

For example: PB000013452S, PB000013452S3s2fss.

How do I parse the varchar value to get the "Number" (13452) in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PATINDEX` to find the position of the first number (that isn't `0`) and then `PATINDEX` again to find the position of the first non-numerical character afterwards. Then use `SUBSTRING` to extract the number:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(V.YourString,PI.I,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',STUFF(V.YourString,1,PI.I-1,''))-1)
FROM (VALUES('PB000013452S'),('PB000013452S3s2fss'))V(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',V.YourString)))PI(I)
```

Answer (score -1):

I write an algorithme for your problem you can try it and i tested befor it works perfectly but i stored numbers in a table  and if you want to concatenate them you can use cursor

```
declare @x varchar(30) = 'PB000013452S3s2fss' /*your string here*/
declare @_len int = len(@x) /*length of your string */
declare @array table (num varchar(30)) /*table for collecte number*/
declare @c int =1 /*counter*/
declare @_char varchar(1) /* to store one char from your  string */
declare @result varchar(30)=''
while @_len>0
begin
    set @_char = SUBSTRING(@x,@c,1)
    if(@_char in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'))
    begin
        while @_len>0
        begin
            set @_char = SUBSTRING(@x,@c,1)
            if(@_char in ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'))
            begin 
            insert into @array values (@_char)
            set @c = @c+1
            set @_len = @_len-1
            end
            else
            set @_len = 0
        end
    end
set @c = @c+1
set @_len = @_len-1
end
select * from @array
```

Comment: Since the rows in a table have no inherent order how do you keep the digits ordered correctly in `@array`? And why do you need a `varchar(30)` column to hold a single character?

Comment: Why a `WHILE` when these are well known to be inherently slow on any RDBMS?